# JMS Block queue with an unacknowledged message

Tags: jms

I would like to know how to block the current queue on the previous unacknowledged message ?
I won't that following messages are consumed while the unacknowledged message is acknowledged.

What is the normal behaviour of JMS in this case ?

Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

I used a transacted session ! When the consumer consumes a message and after process, it is not acknowledged, the session is rollback. And the message is reprovided to the provider.

OK with this practice ? Best solution ?